# Problem with posting to web services within asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service sitting on a dev machine written in python. I am trying to access said webservice using asp.net via the server side. the webservice has been tested and works in every other instance. but when I hit it via asp.net using a post method asp.net doesn't seem to be sending the post values to the webservice at all, everything else is sent fine. If I run the exact same code in a console application everything works 100%.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

class WebService {
    static public String GetContent(String user_id, String content_id) {
        Uri address = new Uri("http://url.to.api/");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
        String response_text = String.Empty;

        // Set type to POST  
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        string data = string.Format("userid={0}&contentid={1}", user_id, content_id);
        byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            response_text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return response_text;
    }
}
```

- updated * with the class more or less thats being used. "url, user/pass".

Also we have checked the information going back and fourth and the webservice never sees the post data... this code as is ran on both a console app and in a asp.net project both hit the webservice, both get a response. the console gets a response with valid information showing that its working, the asp.net project runs and receives and error stating that userid isn't being passed. We have dozens of other sites hitting this webservice with no issues, except non are written in asp.net.

Comment: If the service is complaining that the user id isn't being passed, a proxy will tell you exactly what *is* being passed. That's the best way to start debugging this. Forget about the fact that both ends work outside of this context. This could be anything from a case issue (if the service is case-sensitive), an ssl or certificate problem, missing a carriage return between the headers and content... who knows. But, it's a slam dunk that the problem will be revealed by what's being sent over the wire. There's nothing else that affects success of the transaction.

Comment: it looks like the asp.net side of things is not sending the body to the webservice... I myself am not familiar enough with asp.net or iis is there possibility that there is some sort of security setting in iis stopping this kind of behaviour? there is indeed no ssl or cert problems and we checked case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com)  to view the HTTP transaction between your app and the web service. That should give you a better idea of which end the error is on, and its nature.

You may consider running this against a test "Hello World" service just to test communcations.

Also, post your real code. Change the uri if you want, but what you've quoted above won't compile. The problem may be outside of this snippet.

**update**

How long is it taking for you to receive a reply? Timeout? Running out of connections?

Comment: in both cases (asp.net, console) the reply is almost instant. the webservice is setup that if no userid or contentid is present that it returns a response stating as such, rather then a general 500 error.